# Visual Studio 2015 Windows 10 "Setup Blocked"

Tags: visual-studio-2015, installation

I'm trying to install VS2015 on my windows 10 machine and it will tell me to restart my computer and I've tried it many times but nothing happens and I get the same error?

Here's the error log!

https://pastebin.com/KFz32ME8

Comment: Hi Jase Asmussen, you can have a try with my reply and if not works, please feel free to let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

> [727E4:72628][2017-04-07T19:20:31]i000: MUX:  Stop Block:
>   SystemRebootPendingBlock : The computer needs to be restarted before
>   setup can continue. Please restart the computer and run setup again.

So Windows thinsk it needs a reboot.

[Look at the registry key](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc164360(v=exchg.80).aspx):

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager
```

and check if you can see an entry `PendingFileRenameOperation`

If yes, you can try deleting this value (you should backup the key first).

Now try again to run setup.

Comment: Um, I've rebooted many times and also how do I check if their is a entry thing?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the warning information about checking for windows update, please go to Setting-Windows Update and make sure all pending patches are installed and reboot the computer. Sometimes, the installation of a previous program or Windows update might not complete successfully may be cause this issue, which we can know it from: [The computer needs to be restarted before Setup can continue](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms.exch.setupreadiness.pendingrebootwindowscomponents%28v=exchg.160%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

If this issue persists after re-run the VS 2015 installer as administrator, try to restart your computer not shutdown, you can go to Control Panel\System and Security\Power Options and click Choose what the power button does, turn off fast startup (recommended).

If not works, you can turn hibernation off by running the following command as an administrator:

powercfg.exe /hibernate off

After running it, restart the computer and the setup should work. You can turn it on again by using

powercfg.exe /hibernate on

Answer (score 0):

You need to restart pc (not shutdown and turn-on). If that wont help, then use "[**Ignore-Reboot script.bat**](https://www.protectpages.com/blog/visual-studio-needs-to-be-restarted/)" before starting an installation.